# General approach to modifying an array while looping through it

Tags: arrays, loops, raku

Is it safe in Perl6 (as opposed to perl5 or other languages) to loop through an array while modifying it? For instance, if I have an array of websites to download, and I add failed downloads to the end of the array to re-download, will perl6 behave as expected? (I have about 50k links to download and trying to test all out would be time consuming.)

If not safe, what is a general approach? I have been thinking of storing links of interrupted downloads in another array, and loop through that array after original array was done. However, this is like a fox chasing its tail because I have to store failed downloads in another array (or overwrite the original array).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782864/is-it-safe-to-share-an-array-between-threads

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is definitely safe in a single-threaded environment:

```
my @a = ^5;
for @a { 
    @a.push: $_ + 10 if $_ < 30
}
say @a
```

> `[1 2 3 4 11 12 13 14 21 22 23 24 31 32 33 34]`

In a multi-threaded environment (which is what is better be used in your task) nothing can be taken for granted. Therefore appending of a new element to the array is better be wrapped into a `Lock`:

```
my @a = ^5;
my Lock $l .= new;
for @a {
    start {
        ... # Do your work here 
        $l.protect: {
            @a.push: $_ with $site
        }
    }
}
say @a
```

Note that the last sample won't work as expected because all `start`ed threads must be `await`ed somewhere within the loop. Consider it just as a basic demo.

Yet, locking is usually be avoided whenever possible. A better solution would use `Channel` and `react/whenever` blocks.

Comment: A simple example involving `react`/`whenever` can be found in https://gist.github.com/jnthn/b358ebfb6ea6c366834896b9f62ba92b. One interesting thing to note is that it doesn't have to keep an array of work to do at all, nor worry about termination (when there's no outstanding requests, the `react` block naturally terminates).

Comment: Thank you very much Vadim Belman and Jonathan Worthington for your clarifications. Your suggestions really helped. I will look into react/whenever. Thanks!!!

Comment: In a multi-threaded case, you can also use a [Channel](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Channel) (thread-safe queue) instead of an array, not not worry about Locking.