# Do race conditions occur while reading large data blocks?

Tags: multithreading, atomic, raku

I have 20 threads that all start by reading from one huge data array. Most of the time the codes run smoothly. However, once in a while, without reproducible pattern, one or two threads will say no data.

I think it may be a race condition among the threads while reading the huge array. I plan to implement sleep routine or atomic lock. But race conditions should not occur while reading from a memory block, right?

Comment: If the memory block is constant while the threads are reading, it should be ok.  But please, provide some code that shows the problem, so we can look into it.  Also, you might want to upgrade to the latest Rakudo, as I recall some race issues were recently fixed.

Comment: Please also provide system details, especially your CPU (Intel, AMD, PowerPC, ...?) and memory, just in case that's relevant. (cf [Hardware Memory Models](https://research.swtch.com/hwmm), the discussion that starts at "Data-Race-Free Sequential Consistency", the fundamentally distinct approaches taken by Intel vs AMD/PowerPC, and use of barriers by PL implementors.)

Comment: (Btw, to be clear, I'm not expecting anyone to read the link I just provided unless they're *interested* in these extremely low level details. If such hardware stuff matters, then it's due to a problem in MoarVM, not anyone's Raku code. It's also very unlikely, but I see it as critically important we get to the bottom of any data races anyone encounters.)

Comment: Thank you very much Elizabeth Mattijsen and raiph!!! The array is constant, non-lazy, but is about 10G is size. It is constructed after reading a text file of about 4G is size. Intel i9 256G, 20 threads in code. Each thread reads part of the array. Problem disappeared (for now) after I implemented atomic lock in each thread (atomicint $oneLock) and make each thread sleep $threadID before proceeding. I will check on the link above. Again, thank you very much!!!

Comment: BTW, even though all threads read different sets of indices of the huge array, they all need to read @array[0] FIRST to set up data for computation of other array elements, and that's where the problem arises, and the timing of the problem is at the beginning of executions of the threads. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR** Is your array *100%* **eager**?

Excerpting from [@jnthn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43792718/1077672) to SO question **Is it safe, to share an array between threads?** and adding my own *italic* and **bold** emphasis:

> | Concurrent operations | Variable size array |
> | --- | --- |
> | Read-only, non-lazy | Safe |
> | Read/write or **lazy** | Not safe |
>
> ...
>
> *it is only safe if* [arrays] will *only be **read** from* during the period they are being shared **[and]** *if they're **not lazy*** (though given array assignment is mostly eager, you're not likely to hit that situation by accident).

---

Given that the above is both gospel (or the next best thing), and eminently logical, my guess is your array isn't 100% eager. That and/or there's a Raku(do) bug.

---

Summarizing, your situation is:

**EITHER**

1. You need to fix your code

   You haven't previously noticed that your array is not 100% eager. You need to address the laziness by eliminating it before the first attempt at reading data that's lazily written.

   Try writing `@array.elems` (which forces immediate reification of the entire array) before the first attempt at reading. (Or insert an explicit `eager` in the right spot.) Does that fix the problem?

**OR**

2. There's a bug in Raku(do)

   Either core devs just haven't previously noticed and recorded it, or it's been recorded in one of the bug queues and we/I failed to find it.

Comment: Thank you very much raiph!!! The array in my code is non-lazy but large. Problem seems to have disappeared (for now) after I added atomicint $oneLock to each thread and made each thread sleep $threadID before starting to read the array. I will try @array.elems instead of sleep/lock to see if the problem can also be solved. Thanks!!!

Comment: @lisprogtor The situation you've described -- it's broken just because it's big -- is an abomination to me. If there's anything blocking you from privately sharing with Liz your data, or a sample/description of it, and code (so that core devs can get to the bottom of what's going on), please let us know what we might be able to do to get past that blockage.